# Modify toString() method JComboBox Swing

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a Proveedores class with ID, Name, Lastname and I want add this object into the combobox.

```
      ListIterator listaNombre = listaProveedores.listIterator();
        listado = new Proveedores[listaProveedores.size()];
        int cont = 0;
        while (listaNombre.hasNext()) {
            prov = (Proveedores) listaNombre.next();
            listado[cont] = prov;
            cont++;
        }
this.vista.cArticuloFamilia.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(listado));
```

With this code I add the differents objects into the combobox. It works. But now I want to override the toString method for show only Name attribute. Now combobox shows me the name class (Proveedores) and the ID.

```
entidades.Proveedores[idProveedores=1]
```

How can I override it to show the Proveedores Name?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you subclass Proveedores to override the method?

Comment: Better still -- don't depend on `toString()` but instead use a custom renderer. The `toString()` method override should be used for program debugging rather than for displaying to the user.

Comment: @area404 nononononononono ... while you can override toString for several reasons (mainly for internal logging/debugging), doing so for view reasons is _not_ recommended: the Swing means for configuring the display of any object is a custom xxCellRenderer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a custom [ListCellRenderer](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JComboBoxsetRendererListCellRendereraRenderer.htm) to accomplish this.

You shouldn't tailor toString() to produce GUI data for complex objects.  It is meant for an internal data representation for the developers eyes, not the users.

Comment: Couldn't say it better myself. 1+

Comment: @kleopatra no suprise: every swing control by default uses toString and you have to derive a new renderer just to change the displayed string... (-;

Comment: @morpheus05 yeah, but you do it once: implement some kind of plug-in mechanism that allows your custom renderer to use something else. Or use SwingX which provides full support for pluggable (string, icon) representation plus a separate visual decoration :-)

Comment: @kleopatra That's true and of course I personally already use swingX which every sensible swing dev should use - its great work! Especially the StringValue stuff where you can easily delegate the label generation back to the model.

Comment: Using a custom renderer breaks navigation by keyboard, and if you are just showing a string in a combobox then there is no need to install a different renderer, because the rendering mechanism is exactly the same. It renders the string. Only the input string is different. So imo it is better to modify how the string is delivered to the default renderer, which is overriding toString. But, I would use a wrapper class dedicated to be used in Swing components, because as already said, toString should normally be used for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 9):

Java uses **toString()** to get the String representation of the Object by default it will return fully qualified classname @ followed by hashCode of the object.

Use [ListCellRenderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) to display Proveedores Name in the ComboBox.

**Sample Code:**

```
public static class ProveedoresRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent( JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus ) {
        Object item = value;

        // if the item to be rendered is Proveedores then display it's Name
        if( item instanceof Proveedores ) {
            item = ( ( Proveedores ) item ).getName();
        }
        return super.getListCellRendererComponent( list, item, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
    }
}
```

then set the **ProveedoresRenderer** to the **JComboBox**.

```
ListIterator listaNombre = listaProveedores.listIterator();
listado = new Proveedores[listaProveedores.size()];
int cont = 0;
while (listaNombre.hasNext()) {
    prov = (Proveedores) listaNombre.next();
    listado[cont] = prov;
    cont++;
}
this.vista.cArticuloFamilia.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(listado));

// Set custom renderer to the combobox
this.vista.cArticuloFamilia.setRenderer( new ProveedoresRenderer() );
```